# Get element id's within viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, getboundingclientrect

I have an iframe added inside a div tag. Iframe content has tag "sec" with specific id, like,

```
<p>
<sec id='1'>some text</sec>
<sec id='2'>some other text</sec>
</p>
```

Iframe content spreads horizontally using column width and column gap. Div is scrollable as per the iframes width.

What I need to find is the first and last id value of 'sec' tag which is visible in viewport currently.

I found about getBoundingClientRect but not clear on how it can be used?

Also the concern is that will it not increase processing load since we need to run a loop to check for each tag position?

Can anyone shade some light on it?

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` is relative to the viewport/window the elements are contained in, ie it returns the position inside the iframe. Do you need to know if the elements are visible inside the iframe? Or do you need to know if they are visible inside the iframe _and_ if the iframe is visible inside the main window?

Comment: If performance matters or using jQuery works for you, you might want to have a look at [jQuery.isInView](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview), a component I have written, which does the job (and does it very fast) and works for iframes.

Comment: I need to find all the id of the divs or tags which are visible within that viewport. Is it possible to get first and last element in the visible area with your plugin?

Comment: You hand it a jQuery collection, consisting of the elements you want to examine (your sec elements), and it returns the filtered collection, containing only the visible elements. Just pick the first and the last element in the result set.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be solution. Let me try and test it with my project.

Comment: I should add that if you need to determine visibility of the elements in the iframe with respect to the _outer_ viewport, my plugin doesn't help you that much. You'd have to implement something yourself, e.g. establish the positions of the elements inside the iframe with `getBoundingClientRect`, and the position of the iframe inside the window (also with `getBoundingClientRect`). Then calculate the absolute positions of the elements. It's fussy, though, and doing it _fast_ is not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get the id of the first and last visible element inside an iframe, using [jQuery.isInView](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview):

```
var $iframe = $( yourIframeSelector ),
    _document = $iframe[0].contentDocument,

    $elements = $( yourElementSelector, _document ),
    $visible = $elements.inView( _document ),

    firstId = $visible.first().attr( "id" ),
    lastId = $visible.last().attr( "id" );
```

Comment: I had to do few changes but it works great, thanks! Accepting as answer.